# Execute a script in Google App Engine python environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way that I can just run my GAE script - or a *portion* thereof in the GAE development environment without running it as a whole/entire web server?

i.e. I'd like to just run my function as a command line executable, as opposed to having to start the whole dev server, and issuing a CURL call into the web server - the stopping everything, etc.

Any way to do this?

Comment: If your using Eclipse, you can right click on the file and select Run As (or Debug As) then Python Run. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No - It needs to bind into the whoe GAE dev/test runtime. That's what I can't figure out how to do outside of their canned dev webserver environment. If I do what you said - things like the NDB and other Google-specific libraries don't work.

Comment: I've been trying to do this for years, but as far as I know it's not possible (at least not 'out of the box'). What I have done as a workaround, is create a handler which responds to /debug/.*, with a few lines of code to run whatever method. It's not ideal, but has worked quite well for me. I can post some code if you need

Comment: Thanks @GwynHowell I was thinking about doing the same - and evoking it with a "curl" command.